# How to calculate Body fat content in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Formula**

for Women (1.20 x BMI) + (0.23 x Age) - 5.4
for male  (1.20 x BMI) + (0.23 x Age) - 16.2

I want to create an SQL query to calculate the Body fat content using the above formula.
lets say BMI = 24 and age = 28

Comment: What is you table schema?

Comment: So what's stopping you, exactly? If you had 2 columns called `BMI` and `Age`, both expressions would just work.

Comment: Just replace the `x` by `*`. See also: [SQL CASE Statement - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) for the selection of the women or male subtractor.

Comment: i have a confusion because male and female have different value in the formula so i want to create an sql query in a proper way so that it wont have any issues later

Comment: Not related to your technical question, but BMI has little correlation to body fat. BMI is a formula that is comprised of only height and weight. Two individuals can be the same in both metrics and have vastly different body fat percentages. An extreme example is a professional bodybuilder who weighs 120 kg at a height of 175 cm on stage and a completely sedentary individual with the same height/weight. I guarantee that the former is below 5% while the latter is likely to be over 30%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` for the conditional expression. For example, with a column named `Gender`:

```
SELECT
  CASE Gender 
     WHEN 'female' THEN (1.20 * BMI) + (0.23 * Age) - 5.4
     WHEN 'male'   THEN (1.20 * BMI) + (0.23 * Age) - 16.2
  END
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Yes, or do the CASE selection only for the last term `5.4`/`16.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wanted to put it in a select? If so you could just use this:

`((1.20 x BMI) + (0.23 x Age)) - (5.4 for male (1.20 x BMI) + (0.23 x Age) - 16.2) AS WOMEN_BODY_FAT`

Your BMI and AGE will also getting value automatically if there are containt in the table WOMAN.

Comment: there is no content as women in the table, women and male is from the formula

Comment: Then witch table has the information for the BMI and AGE

Comment: this is how i write to get the bmi and bai value   select *,ROUND(((cast(Weight as float)/cast(Height as float) /cast(Height as float)) * 10000),2) AS BMI
                         ,ROUND(((cast(Hip as float)/(cast(Height as float) / cast(100 as float) * sqrt(cast(Height as float) / cast(100 as float))))-18),2) AS BAI

Comment: You could use then use the case expression if you want to differentiate the male and female and use different formula for each of them